# Play Framework file upload empty params

Tags: java, apache, playframework, java-8, playframework-1.x

Im working on a Play Framework 1.4 application using Apache2.4 as my webserver.

I am trying to do a basic file upload however if I try to upload a file that is larger than 487KB the params are empty, if i upload a file thats less than 487KB the params are there and I can acccess the file from the tmp path. Here is the code:

```
// File <= 487KB Logs "params: {file=[Ljava.lang.String;@160b7aab}"
// File > 487KB Logs "params: {}"
public static String uploadFile() {
    Logger.info("params: %s", params.all());
    return "";
}
```

I have my apache config setup to allow large size payloads and headers:

```
LimitRequestFields 0
LimitRequestBody 0
LimitRequestFieldSize 2097152
```

Any advice on this would be great.

Comment: Also not sure if this helps but if I send extra params in the payload along with the file they are present when the file is less than 487KB but not when the file is larger than 487KB. It looks like a payload size issue but cant see any settings in either Play or Apache that are limiting this.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it turns out this was a Play Framework configuration limit. Quite hard to find nested within their documentation. You need to set the Max Content Length to whatever size files you want to upload (in bytes):

```
play.netty.maxContentLength = 2097152
```

Alternately if you dont want a max size you can set it to `-1`.

```
play.netty.maxContentLength = -1
```

[Documentation here](https://www.playframework.com/modules/netty-1.0/home#aConfigurationa)